# How to set name of column visible when export excel plugin tabletool?

Tags: jquery, excel, datatables

I try use tabletool export to excel. In my table have four column : Name, Birthday, Age, Salary. (column Age and Salary is visible). Ok , i want export to excel with name header of column, but i don't know .Please give me some advice.

```
<table id="div_table" class="display cell-border compact" style="width: 100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Name</td>
                            <td>Birthday</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
"aoColumns": [
{ "mData": "NAME", "aTargets": [0], "sType": "string" },
{ "mData": "BIRTHDAY", "aTargets": [1], "sType": "string" },
{ "mData": "AGE", "aTargets": [2], "sType": "string", "bVisible": false, "bSearchable": false, "orderable": false },
{ "mData": "SALARY", "aTargets": [3], "sType": "string", "bVisible": false, "bSearchable": false, "orderable": false }
],
             "tableTools": {
                "aButtons": [
                     {
                         "sExtends": "xls",
                         "mColumns": [0, 2, 3]
                     }
                ]
            }
```

The result in file excel as

```
Name        
Green     20     20.000
Blue       15     15.000
Red        10     10.000
```

Not see name header of column 2 & 3 . Can i set them with define name ? . Thank guys.

Comment: What part of your code does the Excel export? The code shows HTML and something below the HTML. What is that? What do you expect that to do?

Comment: Please read code clear above .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution , It's work for me , using  "sTitle":

```
 "sTitle": "Name_Of_Column",
```